# Optimizing large join in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently working on the StackOverflow dataset from Google BigQuery Public datasets.

I want to find which are the top users by numQuestions/Answers in a given country and tag (perhaps even with their question favs, answer score etc)

I think the query would be sped up if I first compute a data set with userid, tag, numQuestions, numAnswers, etc

So I did

```
usersQuestionsDf = spark.sql("""
    SELECT uid, tag, COUNT(*) AS numQuestions, SUM(favorite_count) AS favs
    FROM (
        SELECT u.id AS uid, explode(q.tags) AS tag, q.favorite_count
        FROM usersFixedCountries u
        INNER JOIN questions q
        ON q.owner_user_id = u.id
        WHERE country IS NOT NULL
    )
    GROUP BY uid, tag
""")

usersAnswersDf = spark.sql("""
    SELECT uid, tag, SUM(score) AS score, COUNT(*) AS numAnswers
    FROM (
        SELECT u.id AS uid, explode(q.tags) AS tag, a.score
        FROM usersFixedCountries u
        INNER JOIN answers a
        ON a.owner_user_id = u.id
        INNER JOIN questions q
        ON q.id = a.parent_id
        WHERE country is NOT NULL
    )
    GROUP BY uid, tag
""")
```

Then I tried to do:

```
usersAnswersDf.createOrReplaceTempView("usersAnswers")
usersQuestionsDf.createOrReplaceTempView("usersQuestions")
usersTagScoreDf = spark.sql("""
    SELECT q.uid, q.tag, numAnswers, score AS answersScore, numQuestions, favs AS questionsFavs, u.display_name, u.up_votes
    FROM usersAnswers a
    FULL OUTER JOIN usersQuestions q
    ON q.uid = a.uid
    AND q.tag = a.tag
    INNER JOIN usersFixedCountries u
    ON u.id = q.uid
    WHERE u.country IS NOT NULL
""")
```

The problem is the last part throws an error. I think it ran out of memory. So I am wondering how might I optimize this? Maybe my query is just inefficient?

```
An error occurred while calling o132.showString.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange hashpartitioning(uid#350, 200)
+- *Project [score#391L, numAnswers#392L, uid#350, tag#355, numQuestions#352L, favs#353L]
   +- *BroadcastHashJoin [uid#389, tag#394], [uid#350, tag#355], RightOuter, BuildLeft
      :- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, int, true], input[1, string, true]))
      :  +- InMemoryTableScan [uid#389, tag#394, score#391L, numAnswers#392L]
      :        +- InMemoryRelation [uid#389, tag#394, score#391L, numAnswers#392L], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
      :              +- *HashAggregate(keys=[uid#175, tag#180], functions=[sum(cast(score#33 as bigint)), count(1)], output=[uid#175, tag#180, score#177L, numAnswers#178L])
      :                 +- Exchange hashpartitioning(uid#175, tag#180, 200)
      :                    +- *HashAggregate(keys=[uid#175, tag#180], functions=[partial_sum(cast(score#33 as bigint)), partial_count(1)], output=[uid#175, tag#180, sum#189L, count#190L])
      :                       +- *Project [id#82 AS uid#175, tag#180, score#33]
      :                          +- Generate explode(tags#2), true, false, [tag#180]
      :                             +- *Project [id#82, score#33, tags#2]
      :                                +- *SortMergeJoin [parent_id#32], [id#0], Inner
      :                                   :- *Sort [parent_id#32 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :                                   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(parent_id#32, 200)
      :                                   :     +- *Project [id#82, parent_id#32, score#33]
      :                                   :        +- *SortMergeJoin [id#82], [owner_user_id#31], Inner
      :                                   :           :- *Sort [id#82 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :                                   :           :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#82, 200)
      :                                   :           :     +- *Project [id#82]
      :                                   :           :        +- *Filter (isnotnull(country#89) && isnotnull(id#82))
      :                                   :           :           +- *FileScan parquet [id#82,country#89] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[wasb://data@cs4225.blob.core.windows.net/parquet/usersFixedCountries.parquet], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(country), IsNotNull(id)], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,country:string>
      :                                   :           +- *Sort [owner_user_id#31 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :                                   :              +- Exchange hashpartitioning(owner_user_id#31, 200)
      :                                   :                 +- *Project [owner_user_id#31, parent_id#32, score#33]
      :                                   :                    +- *Filter (isnotnull(owner_user_id#31) && isnotnull(parent_id#32))
      :                                   :                       +- *FileScan parquet [owner_user_id#31,parent_id#32,score#33,creation_year#36] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[wasb://data@cs4225.blob.core.windows.net/parquet/answers.parquet], PartitionCount: 11, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(owner_user_id), IsNotNull(parent_id)], ReadSchema: struct<owner_user_id:int,parent_id:int,score:int>
      :                                   +- *Sort [id#0 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :                                      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#0, 200)
      :                                         +- *Project [id#0, tags#2]
      :                                            +- *Filter isnotnull(id#0)
      :                                               +- *FileScan parquet [id#0,tags#2,creation_year#12] Batched: false, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[wasb://data@cs4225.blob.core.windows.net/parquet/questions.parquet], PartitionCount: 11, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(id)], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,tags:array<string>>
      +- *Filter isnotnull(uid#350)
         +- InMemoryTableScan [uid#350, tag#355, numQuestions#352L, favs#353L], [isnotnull(uid#350)]
               +- InMemoryRelation [uid#350, tag#355, numQuestions#352L, favs#353L], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                     +- *HashAggregate(keys=[uid#112, tag#117], functions=[count(1), sum(cast(favorite_count#9 as bigint))], output=[uid#112, tag#117, numQuestions#114L, favs#115L])
                        +- Exchange hashpartitioning(uid#112, tag#117, 200)
                           +- *HashAggregate(keys=[uid#112, tag#117], functions=[partial_count(1), partial_sum(cast(favorite_count#9 as bigint))], output=[uid#112, tag#117, count#126L, sum#127L])
                              +- *Project [id#82 AS uid#112, tag#117, favorite_count#9]
                                 +- Generate explode(tags#2), true, false, [tag#117]
                                    +- *Project [id#82, tags#2, favorite_count#9]
                                       +- *SortMergeJoin [id#82], [owner_user_id#3], Inner
                                          :- *Sort [id#82 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                                          :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#82, 200)
                                          :     +- *Project [id#82]
                                          :        +- *Filter (isnotnull(country#89) && isnotnull(id#82))
                                          :           +- *FileScan parquet [id#82,country#89] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[wasb://data@cs4225.blob.core.windows.net/parquet/usersFixedCountries.parquet], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(country), IsNotNull(id)], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,country:string>
                                          +- *Sort [owner_user_id#3 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                                             +- Exchange hashpartitioning(owner_user_id#3, 200)
                                                +- *Project [tags#2, owner_user_id#3, favorite_count#9]
                                                   +- *Filter isnotnull(owner_user_id#3)
                                                      +- *FileScan parquet [tags#2,owner_user_id#3,favorite_count#9,creation_year#12] Batched: false, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[wasb://data@cs4225.blob.core.windows.net/parquet/questions.parquet], PartitionCount: 11, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(owner_user_id)], ReadSchema: struct<tags:array<string>,owner_user_id:int,favorite_count:int>
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange.doExecute(ShuffleExchange.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec.inputRDDs(SortExec.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinExec.inputRDDs(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2861)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2842)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2841)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:241)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doExecuteBroadcast(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeBroadcast(SparkPlan.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.prepareBroadcast(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.codegenOuter(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.doConsume(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.consume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.doConsume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doProduce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.doProduce(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.produce(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doCodeGen(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:372)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchange.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchange.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchange.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
    ... 55 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 336, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o132.showString.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange hashpartitioning(uid#350, 200)
+- *Project [score#391L, numAnswers#392L, uid#350, tag#355, numQuestions#352L, favs#353L]
   +- *BroadcastHashJoin [uid#389, tag#394], [uid#350, tag#355], RightOuter, BuildLeft
      :- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, int, true], input[1, string, true]))
      :  +- InMemoryTableScan [uid#389, tag#394, score#391L, numAnswers#392L]
      :        +- InMemoryRelation [uid#389, tag#394, score#391L, numAnswers#392L], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
      :              +- *HashAggregate(keys=[uid#175, tag#180], functions=[sum(cast(score#33 as bigint)), count(1)], output=[uid#175, tag#180, score#177L, numAnswers#178L])
      :                 +- Exchange hashpartitioning(uid#175, tag#180, 200)
      :                    +- *HashAggregate(keys=[uid#175, tag#180], functions=[partial_sum(cast(score#33 as bigint)), partial_count(1)], output=[uid#175, tag#180, sum#189L, count#190L])
      :                       +- *Project [id#82 AS uid#175, tag#180, score#33]
      :                          +- Generate explode(tags#2), true, false, [tag#180]
      :                             +- *Project [id#82, score#33, tags#2]
      :                                +- *SortMergeJoin [parent_id#32], [id#0], Inner
      :                                   :- *Sort [parent_id#32 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :                                   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(parent_id#32, 200)
      :                                   :     +- *Project [id#82, parent_id#32, score#33]
      :                                   :        +- *SortMergeJoin [id#82], [owner_user_id#31], Inner
      :                                   :           :- *Sort [id#82 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :                                   :           :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#82, 200)
      :                                   :           :     +- *Project [id#82]
      :                                   :           :        +- *Filter (isnotnull(country#89) && isnotnull(id#82))
      :                                   :           :           +- *FileScan parquet [id#82,country#89] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[wasb://data@cs4225.blob.core.windows.net/parquet/usersFixedCountries.parquet], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(country), IsNotNull(id)], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,country:string>
      :                                   :           +- *Sort [owner_user_id#31 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :                                   :              +- Exchange hashpartitioning(owner_user_id#31, 200)
      :                                   :                 +- *Project [owner_user_id#31, parent_id#32, score#33]
      :                                   :                    +- *Filter (isnotnull(owner_user_id#31) && isnotnull(parent_id#32))
      :                                   :                       +- *FileScan parquet [owner_user_id#31,parent_id#32,score#33,creation_year#36] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[wasb://data@cs4225.blob.core.windows.net/parquet/answers.parquet], PartitionCount: 11, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(owner_user_id), IsNotNull(parent_id)], ReadSchema: struct<owner_user_id:int,parent_id:int,score:int>
      :                                   +- *Sort [id#0 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :                                      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#0, 200)
      :                                         +- *Project [id#0, tags#2]
      :                                            +- *Filter isnotnull(id#0)
      :                                               +- *FileScan parquet [id#0,tags#2,creation_year#12] Batched: false, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[wasb://data@cs4225.blob.core.windows.net/parquet/questions.parquet], PartitionCount: 11, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(id)], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,tags:array<string>>
      +- *Filter isnotnull(uid#350)
         +- InMemoryTableScan [uid#350, tag#355, numQuestions#352L, favs#353L], [isnotnull(uid#350)]
               +- InMemoryRelation [uid#350, tag#355, numQuestions#352L, favs#353L], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                     +- *HashAggregate(keys=[uid#112, tag#117], functions=[count(1), sum(cast(favorite_count#9 as bigint))], output=[uid#112, tag#117, numQuestions#114L, favs#115L])
                        +- Exchange hashpartitioning(uid#112, tag#117, 200)
                           +- *HashAggregate(keys=[uid#112, tag#117], functions=[partial_count(1), partial_sum(cast(favorite_count#9 as bigint))], output=[uid#112, tag#117, count#126L, sum#127L])
                              +- *Project [id#82 AS uid#112, tag#117, favorite_count#9]
                                 +- Generate explode(tags#2), true, false, [tag#117]
                                    +- *Project [id#82, tags#2, favorite_count#9]
                                       +- *SortMergeJoin [id#82], [owner_user_id#3], Inner
                                          :- *Sort [id#82 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                                          :  +- Exchange
```

Comment: Which version of Spark do you use?

Comment: @Panos spark 2.2

Comment: I guess the problem occurs because of the broadcast exchange. The broadcasted table may be large so it takes time to be broadcasted. You can increase the broadcast timeout or decrease autoBroadcastJoinThreshold. Can you provide your config file and some  info about your cluster? The tables' size would be helpful as well.

Comment: you might try repartitioning the two intermediate tables on id and tag which could mitigate issues by reducing the need to shuffle data.